# Is there a visual guide to the UIKit components?

Tags: iphone, uikit

My Problem is this, I want to add some component to my App I saw in some other App. Everytime I wnat to do this, I start googling around for the name. It took me some time to find the name of UIActionSheet. Now I'm looking for that transparent overlay that appears when you turn the volume up and down.

So, is there a good visual guide to the UIKit components? As an example, see the [visual guide to swing components](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/ui/features/components.html) or this [visual guide](http://sites.google.com/site/iphonedevnote/visual-guide) which is way to short/incomplete. And secondly, what's the name of the component I'm looking for?

Answer (score 7):

The iOS documentation has a section called [iOS UIKit UI Catalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857) that shows the various UI features by name with links to the API docs and recommend how and when they should be used.

Comment: Dead link (at least right now), do you have an alternate, or perhaps a summary you can add if it breaks again?

Comment: @progrmr, the UIKit link https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit just has a class/method documentation right now, probably changed since 2010 when you posted it. can't find any visual clues to what elements are available :-/

Answer (score 6):

Apple has provided a sample iPhone application called UICatalog. It lists all (or most?) of the standard UIKit component in different variants.

You can download the sample from [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/UICatalog/Introduction/Intro.html).

Comment: Thanks, that's a good one, but there are definitely not all UI components in it. E.g. the TabBar is missing.

Comment: That's true, so my "(or most?)" is the right answer. I do however doubt it would be possible to include all UIKit classes into one application, since some of them only makes sence on the root level - meaning they would not be able to co-exist and giving a true look-and-feel.

Comment: You right and I give you an upvote. However, I hope someone could provide a link to a good website.

Answer (score 2):

i recently had the same problem. Googling a lot i came across the following page. This overlay works pretty well and is easy to use.

look at: http://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Well, that answers at least the second part of my question. Thanks and +1.