# Which UI object to do this?

Tags: iphone, ios, user-interface

I have seen many times waiting panels (panels with a `uiactivityindicatorview`) black/dark with some transparency and white labels.
Like this one :

[image]

I guess it is a standard element.
Where can I find it?

Comment: Just a UIView with a transparent background, no?

Comment: I was searching for a visual guide to the cocoa components some time ago, but there seems to be none: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781055/is-there-a-visual-guide-to-the-uikit-components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This. it's the best solution I came across to show the activity. [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/laullon/MBProgressHUD)

Answer (score 0):

As by now there is no standard `UIElement` for that in iOS.

But checkout this [library](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD):

Answer (score 0):

MBProgressHUD looks nice. You might want to check out http://code.google.com/p/toast-notifications-ios/ too.

Answer (score 0):

There's no iOS component that does this.

If you don't want to include an external library just for this one component then you can do it using UI components.

```
/* Warning, typed from memory */

// Create the UIView that's the background
UIView *pleaseWaitView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 80)];
[pleaseWaitView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.5 alpha:0.5]];
[[pleaseWaitView layer] setCornerRadius:5.0f];

// And create an activity indicator
UIActivityIndicator *i = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
[i startAnimating];
[pleaseWaitView addSubview:i];
[i release];

// Add it to the main view (in the middle)
[pleaseWaitView setCenter:CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2, self.view.bounds.size.height/2)];
[self.view addSubview:pleaseWaitView];
```

You can add a UILabel with whatever text you want (in your case, 'Authenticating') in the same way as you added the activity indicator.

The tricky part is setting the corner radius - you will probably need this at the top of your .m file :

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

NB You can do this in interface builder as well if you want (apart from the corner radius bit!) ;)

Answer (score 0):

I answered a question that included an overlay like this. I included the code and the overlay image you need to do it with. Take a look at this answer and take a look at the screen shot it created. I use this overlay as I send email in the background so you will want to edit the code to do your function but the overlay code is already in place.

[Locking the Fields in MFMailComposeViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284599/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-question-locking-the-fields/6287412#6287412)

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [DSActivityView](http://www.dejal.com/developer/dsactivityview).  I've successfully used it in a few of my projects.